A movie where theres a woman tied up with a man with a mask in the room
I remember this videoclip where there's a woman tied up with her face blocking half of the camera. The other half of the camera shows a guy completely black with a mask crawling towards her (very weirdly crawling like he's walking like a dog). It's a pretty famous part I think. Im almost sure the guy with the mask is some serial killer and that he records the murders. The movie is all about finding the killer or something.
I'm 99% sure it's a horror movie. I can't seem to figure out what the movie is.

I'm afraid ID questions need some basic details like country\language, approximate year of release, plot details etc. Do you know anything else about this film?

@Walt He's a serial killer and he records the victims while he kills them. He's always wearing a mask apparently. It should be an american movie.

I found the movie.
I didnt watch the movie myself but I've heard it's very brutal. 
It's: The Poughkeepsie Tapes

In an abandoned house in Poughkeepsie, New York murder investigators uncover hundreds of tapes showing decades of a serial killer's work.




This is the part I was talking about:




The description you made partially matches the below synopsis of 8mm taken from the IMDB, starring Nicholas Cage (specially the last part, the masked man that records the killing of a girl): 

Private investigator Tom Welles is hired by the recently widowed Mrs. Christian who has found a startling pornographic film in her late husband's possessions. In the film a teenage girl is apparently killed and Welles is pretty sure it's a genuine snuff film. He takes the case, first going through records of runaways finally identifying the girl and learning that she may have run off to California. There he enters the seedy underworld of pornography with the help of Max California, a porn store clerk. His principal clue is the masked man who killed the girl as he has a unique tattoo on his hand. He soon finds the culprits but there is little satisfaction in resolving the mystery.

Unfortunately I haven't seen the movie, so I can't be of further help, but could it be this the film you are looking for?
8mm trailer
IMDB
